# Finding an an element with order equal to that of a coset

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose that $K \trianglelefteq G$ with $|K| = m < \infty$. Let $x \in G$ and let $n$ be a positive integer such that $\gcd(m, n) = 1$. Prove that if $o(xK) = n$ (where $xK$ is an element of $G/K$) then there is an element $y\in G$ such that $o(y) = n$ and $xK = yK$.

I know that I need to show that $y^{-1}x \in K$ to show that the two cosets are the same, but I am unable to find an element $y\in G$ of order $n$ which satisfies this property. If $o(x)=n$, the problem becomes trivial, but I don't know what to do when $o(x)\neq n$.

Comment: I take it when you say the order of $xK$ you're viewing $xK$ as an element of the quotient group $G/K$.

Comment: Is $x^m$ the element you're looking for?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, $xK$ is being viewed as a subgroup of the quotient group. 
Would $(x^m)^{-1}x \in K$ always? If yes, how do I prove that?

Comment: @MathNoob $xK$ is not a "subgroup". It's both a coset and an element of $G/K$ but not (in general) a subgroup.

Comment: @ancientmathematician yeah sorry, I meant an element of $G\setminus K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, in problems of this kind the condition $\gcd(m,n)=1$ should make you think of Bezout. Then, there exists $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $am+bn=1$. Now, what do we want? An element $y\in G$ such that $y^n=1$ and $y^{-1}x\in K$. As suggested in the comments, maybe it is reasonable to think that $y$ has to be a power of $x$ (because it is the only element for wich we know something). So let us assume $y=x^\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$. The first condition tells us that $x^{\alpha n}=y^n=1$ and the second condition tells us that $y^{-1}x=x^{1-\alpha}\in K$. Since by hypothesis $x^n\in K$ then $1-\alpha=cn$ for some integer $c$. Now you see what is the most reasonable choice for $\alpha$? You want $1-\alpha=cn$ for some $c$ and you know that  $am+bn=1$, hence maybe you can try $\alpha=am$ and $b=c$.

This is the way to think of this problem. With all this work I don't think you will have any problem to show that $y=x^{am}$ is the solution of the problem.